# Sound for when duct tape is being pulled off of a roll

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds, onomatopoeia

I am trying to find a specific term or onomatopoeia for when tape is being pulled off of a roll, to describe the sound it makes.

Comment: The English word that means "the sound of duct tape coming off" is, coincidentally, the same English word as the one that means "the taste of fresh mango". When you find it, let me know.

Comment: It's called *that sound when* "duct tape is being pulled off of a roll" +1

Comment: ***Quacktttttt!!!***

Comment: It's pretty variable IMO, it can make almost a loud slurping noise, or can be near silent crackle/hiss, depending on speed, angle, freshness, brand, wide or narrow roll, color, if it's metallic, etc.

Comment: I think you'll need to coin a word... I'd suggest zzzuquop pip. How many points is that in scrabble?

Answer (score 4):

**Tape ripping** sound or noise:

[ripping sound of tape_Storyblocks](https://www.storyblocks.com/audio/stock/tape-ripping-noise-bgezsut3ldbk0wxxzom.html)

More ripping:

[tape ripping_Motion Array](https://motionarray.com/sound-effects/tape-ripping-132004/)

Comment: Arguably rrrrrrrrrrip is onomatopoeia.

Answer (score 1):

The term "*shredding noise*" describes this sound closely enough.

> ([Heartbreaker Julie Garwood · 2012](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Heartbreaker/EC1q_0YrI9cC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22shredding+noise%22&pg=PT323&printsec=frontcover))  Then a crash, maybe a vase, Nick thought, followed by a shredding noise, like material being ripped apart.

Here is the sound of a shredder in a video: "[Shredding Paper Sound Effect](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=shredding+noise#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:65988614,vid:a4X6_NZmrks)".

Answer (score 0):

"Zwack!" perhaps.  Or "zwaaack"?

Answer (score 0):

It makes a screeching sound.  *screech*, *streak*, *shriek*